# Get different RefTeX references for Eq. vs. Equation, Fig. vs. Figure

Tags: reftex-mode

When invoking RefTeX to generate LaTeX code for a reference (to an equation, figure) I need a short unbreakable space (LaTeX: `\,`) when the abbreviation is used (`Eq.\,\ref{}, Fig.\,\ref{}`) and a long space (`~`) when the full word is used (`Equation~\ref{}, Figure~\ref{}`).  I thought I understood the `reftex-label-alist` and added to my `init.el`:

```lisp
(add-to-list 'reftex-label-alist '("equation" ?e "eq:" "~\\ref{%s}"   t (regexp "equations?")))

(add-to-list 'reftex-label-alist '("eq"       ?e "eq:" "\\,\\ref{%s}" t (regexp "eqs?\\." "eqn\\.")))
```

i.e. the first line matching "equation(s)" and the second matching "eq(s)", but this always results in a short space.  Is there a way to do this, or am I asking for something impossible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The relevant piece when you make a reference (`\ref`) to a label is the type-indicator, in this case `?e`.  You can't have multiple setups around a single type-indicator.

In your case, you want to set the value of `reftex-format-ref-function`.  The docstring says:

> Function which produces the string to insert as a reference. Normally
> should be nil, because the format to insert a reference can already be
> specified in `reftex-label-alist`.
>
> This hook also is used by the special commands to insert e.g. `\vref`
> and `\fref` references, so even if you set this, your setting will be
> ignored by the special commands.
>
> The function will be called with three arguments, the `LABEL`, the
> `DEFAULT FORMAT`, which normally is `~\ref{%s}` and the `REFERENCE STYLE`.
> The function should return the string to insert into the buffer.

Something like this in your init file should do the job:

```el
(setq reftex-format-ref-function
      (lambda (label fmt ref-style)
        (let ((fmt (if (= (char-before) ?.)
                       (replace-regexp-in-string "~" "\\," fmt nil t)
                     fmt)))
          (format fmt label ref-style))))
```